# Lluís Puig unpublished notes

Tags: fusion-categories

I have been reading Linckelman Notes and the Broto-Levi-Oliver articles about fusion systems and they always make mention about the Lluís Puig notes that he gave years ago, so I'm asking if anyone has a copy in pdf of this notes.

Comment: the obvious thing to do is to ask Prof. Puig directly, contact information is at http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05033

Comment: Done. He told me that the notes were extended to a paper published on 2006, and then he published a book called "Frobenius Categories versus Brauer Blocks". Now he's retired, he's like 71. Very nice man.